# Network Request for 314 kb Background image on Angular 2 app is taking 14 seconds to complete

Tags: css, amazon-s3, angular, xmlhttprequest, page-load-time

I'm having some very frustrating issues with load time on a web application that I'm building and I don't have much experience with networking so my attempts to diagnose the issue aren't getting me too far.

As I said in the description, I'm using Angular 2 to build the app. On the home page there is a full page background image that is compressed down to around 314kb in size. The background image is being placed onto a browser sized div in the home page component's css file. I'm hosting it from an Amazon S3 bucket. I'm using the angular cli tool so I used the 'ng build' command to build the app into the dist/ folder and uploaded it to the s3 bucket. When I went to the endpoint for the bucket to test out the app, It took nearly 14 seconds for the network request to complete for the background image alone.

Below is a cropped screenshot from the 'Network' tab in chrome developer tools. I've noticed two interesting things about the request. The first is that nearly the entire length of the request is in the 'stalled' state, which is represented by the gray bar. I'm not entirely sure what that means or what would be causing it. According to some google documentation for the 'Developer Tools' feature, it usually means that the browser is already making the max amount of requests that it is allowed to make at one time (6 for chrome) and so the request is waiting for one of those to finish before it starts, however that doesn't seem to make sense because for the entire length of time the image request is 'stalled,' it is the only request that hasn't yet completed. The second interesting thing that I noticed is that 'initiator' file for virtually every other request was zone.js, whereas the initiator for the background image request was config.js. I'm not sure if that is of any significance or not, but it seems like it could have something to do with the issue.

[image: Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools]

I'm fairly new to front end development and JavaScript in general so I'm sorry if I'm not providing the right information, but if there is any other info that would help you to understand the issue just let me know and I'll get it for you.

Comment: How long does it take if you just try to download that image directly? Also does it consistently take 14 seconds, or was it only slow one time?